# Sinn und Verwendung von »hochbacken«

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verb

Neulich war auf der Verpackung einer Tiefkühlpizza Folgendes zu lesen:

> Backt Zuhause frisch hoch

Ich kann mir nur schwer vorstellen, dass eine Fertig-Pizza in die Höhe gebacken wird oder ist das vergleichbar mit einem Kuchen, der *aufgeht*?

Wie also ist dieser Ausdruck zu verstehen oder ist das nur eine Marketing-Bezeichnung? Gibt es Regionen, in denen *hochbacken* tatsächlich in diesem Kontext benutzt wird?

Comment: Unbekanntes Wort in den Nischen der Gesellschaft, die ich kenne. Aber Produktverpackungstexter verwenden ja allerlei Begriffe, die sonst keiner verwendet. ("Joghurt mild" etc.)

Comment: Pizza ist ja üblicherweise aus Hefeteig. Je nach Rezeptur backt sie unterschiedlich hoch. Je nach Geschmack trifft das auf mehr oder weniger Begeisterung. Wenn sich der Hersteller um gutes hochbacken bemüht und vielleicht eine Nische besetzen will, so ist das m.E. kein misslungener Ausdruck.

Comment: Du bist offensichtlich nicht der/die erste, der/die sich an diesem Wort stört: http://blogs.taz.de/wortistik/2007/04/24/hochbacken/

Comment: @UserUnknown   Willst du mit deinem Kommentar, der dem möglicherweise unkundigen Leser die Eigenschaften von Hefeteig erläutert, nebenbei andeuten, dass du das Wort "hochbacken" in deinem aktiven Wortschatz hast?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Hatte ich bislang nicht und wollte es auch nicht ausdrücken. "Ist m.E. kein misslungener Ausdruck" sollte darstellen, dass es womöglich eine Eigenschöpfung ist. Zu Hefeteig fällt mir als erstes "aufgehen" ein - ob ich darauf einen griffigen Werbeslogan gegründet hätte, weiß ich nicht. "Backt frisch hoch" oder "Geht frisch auf" finde ich beide etwas befremdlich, als ob das "frisch" mit Zwang mit reingemusst hat. Ähnlich befremdet mich das "Zuhause". Wo sonst? Auf dem Heimweg? Die Wortbildung "hochbacken" finde ich aber legitim und verständlich.

Answer (score 2):

> hochbacken

wie in dem zitierten Beispiel habe ich noch nie gehört. Das Gemeinte erschließt sich freilich aus Kontext und Bestandteilen. Kommentator *user unknown* hat oben ja schon die relevanten Erläuterungen zum Hefeteig gegeben. Dort, wo ich Deutsch spreche, höre, schreibe und lese, ist mir das Wort bisher nicht untergekommen.

Als im Sprachgebrauch existent kann ich aber

> ausbacken

bestätigen. In der Alltagssprache schwäbischer Dörfer, in denen ich mich früher öfters mal bewegte, verwendet man dies für die Tätigkeit des Frittierens (in heißem Öl garen) von, ja, eben: Fettgebackenem wie etwa Krapfen. Die ihrerseits wieder aus Hefeteig aber auch aus anderen Teigsorten sein können.

Das, was die Tiefkühlpizzafirma *hochbacken* nennt, kenne ich eher als

> aufgehen

(der Teig geht auf; der Teig ist schön aufgegangen; Mist, der Teig geht nicht richtig auf). Dies bezeichnet aber die Volumensänderung des Teigs in der Ruhephase vor dem backen und (!) während des Backens. Ich hätte also Verständnis dafür, wenn man in einer differenzierten Diskussion der Produktionsprozesse von Hefeteigprodukten ein eigenes Wort haben möchte für die Volumenszunahme des Teigs unter Hitzeeinfluss. Offenbar hat die Backindustrie sich hier für *hochbacken* entschieden.